# Java generics bug?

Tags: java, generics

Let's have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class MyType {
}

public class MySuperclass<T extends MyType> {
    protected Map<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    protected String myMethod(String s) {
        return myMap.get(s);
    }
}

public class MySubclass extends MySuperclass {
    @Override
    protected String myMethod(String s) {
        return myMap.get(s); // <-- compilation error
    }
}
```

Why there is a compilation error in the overriden method of `MySubclass`?
The error message is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String".

The interesting thing is that the compilation error dissapears if I define generics class type for `MySuperclass` in `MySubclass` definition:

```
public class MySubclass extends MySuperclass<MyType> {
    @Override
    protected String myMethod(String s) {
        return myMap.get(s);
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain this behavior? I would consider it to be a Java compiler bug.

I'm using jdk1.6.0_24.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a bug. By extending `MySuperclass` instead of `MySuperclass<MyType>`, you're extending the *raw type* `MySuperclass`, which means that `myMap` will also be of type `Map` instead of `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: exactly. That was one of Bloch's "puzzlers".

Comment: So generics is all or nothing? If you use a raw type, you will not get any generics for that type, not even the parts that do not depend on `T` at all?

Comment: But what has generic definition of `MySuperclass**<MyType>**` in common with generics of `Map**<String, String>** myMap`? Those are two different generics definitions with no 'connection' between them. I don't get it.

Comment: @miso The [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257) explains it in great detail

Comment: Yeah, it's strange.  But that's just the way Java works - raw types are entirely raw.

Comment: @Thilo: keep in mind that raw types **only** exist for backwards compatibility. **If** you use a raw type, then the compiler assumes your code knows *nothing* about generics. That's necessary to be able to enhance existing libraries with generics without breaking old non-generic code.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed unreasonable. This can be considered a bug in design. The root cause is the decision to keep generified collection API backward compatible, instead of keeping the old one intact and introducing new generified API. This decision is technically nonsense, and their explanations are laughable. The real reason behind it is probably Sun was compelled to push out Java5 but didn't have enough resource, so they took the easy route (erasure). So here we are, totally screwed. This bastard type system not only is a problem in itself, it's also a great obstacle for introducing any new feature.

Answer (score 0):

if Foo is a subtype (subclass or subinterface) of Bar, and G is some
generic type declaration, it is not the case that G is a subtype of G.

You can refer 
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf (for more information)